# Retrieving year and month in YYYYMM format using datetime.now

Tags: c#, datetime

I need year and month of date in YYYYMM format.
I am trying to use

```
string yrmm = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
```

But this returns '20114' instead of '201104'. Any easy way to fix this?

Answer (score 59):

Date Formatting in C#

```
<%= String.Format("{specifier}", DateTime.Now) %>

Specifier ---> Description ---> Output
d ---> Short Date ---> 08/04/2007
D ---> Long Date ---> 08 April 2007
t ---> Short Time ---> 21:08
T ---> Long Time ---> 21:08:59
f ---> Full date and time ---> 08 April 2007 21:08
F ---> Full date and time (long) ---> 08 April 2007 21:08:59
g ---> Default date and time ---> 08/04/2007 21:08
G ---> Default date and time (long) ---> 08/04/2007 21:08:59
M ---> Day / Month ---> 08 April
r ---> RFC1123 date ---> Sun, 08 Apr 2007 21:08:59 GMT
s ---> Sortable date/time ---> 2007-04-08T21:08:59
u ---> Universal time, local timezone ---> 2007-04-08 21:08:59Z
Y ---> Month / Year ---> April 2007
dd ---> Day ---> 08
ddd ---> Short Day Name ---> Sun
dddd ---> Full Day Name ---> Sunday
hh ---> 2 digit hour ---> 09
HH ---> 2 digit hour (24 hour) ---> 21
mm ---> 2 digit minute ---> 08
MM ---> Month ---> 04
MMM ---> Short Month name ---> Apr
MMMM ---> Month name ---> April
ss ---> seconds ---> 59
tt ---> AM/PM ---> PM
yy ---> 2 digit year ---> 07
yyyy ---> 4 digit year ---> 2007
: ---> seperator, e.g. {0:hh:mm:ss} ---> 09:08:59
/ ---> seperator, e.g. {0:dd/MM/yyyy} ---> 08/04/2007
```

This worked great for me greatly... This will work for you as well

Comment: Can you please format your answer so that the code is included in code blocks?

Comment: This looks like a copy and paste from a site, should answer the question clearly and provide links to any resources used.

Comment: Good resource, but you should provide links.

Comment: Useful stuff. Its better to give a courtesy, if it taken from some ones

Answer (score 46):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMM");
```

Documentation on DateTime Format strings is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMM");
```

See you

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ToString method of DateTime:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMM");
```

An overview of several predefined and user defined format strings can be found here:

- [Predefined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)
- [Custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)